# Importing Large File from MariaDB "Killed" by sqlcmd

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mariadb, sqlcmd

I have a database in MariaDB.  I used the following command to export my Database from MariaDB

```
mysqldump MyDB --skip-extended-insert --compatible=mssql >mssql3.sql
```

Then I tried the following command to import into MS SQL Server

```
sqlcmd -U sa -P 'NotMyRealPassword' -S localhost -i mssql3.sql -d MyDB -t 65534
```

however the only output I get after about 30 seconds is "Killed".  Google Fu hasn't gotten me anywhere.  Anyone else know what this might be?

I have also tried without skip insert with same result:

```
mysqldump MyDB --compatible=mssql >mssql3.sql
```

Its not a huge database, but its not small either.  SQL file is about 600MB

Comment: SQL Server and MariaDB are completely different products. They don't have the same file formats or backup formats. They don't use the same SQL dialect. A dump isn't a backup anyway, it's just a SQL script in the database's current dialect. It won't execute even between different versions of the same database if eg types are different. `Logical backup` is terminology used when vendors either don't have real (physical) backups or want to charge extra for them.

Comment: In short, it's unclear what you're trying to do. If you assumed you can just take a MariaDB SQL script and  run it on a different product, like PostgreSQL, Oracle or SQL Server, the assumption is wrong. Different products have different types to begin with. Use SQL Server Migration Assistant instead, to convert the schema and then copy the data converting types as needed

Comment: `the only output I get after about 30 seconds is "Killed` what's the *exact, actual console output*? `sqlcmd` wouldn't print `Killed`. 30 seconds sounds like a connection timeout. By default there's no query timeout. Is SQL Server up and running on the local machine? Are you trying to connect to a SQL Server Express instance perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

## SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL (MySQLToSQL)

> MicrosoftSQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) for MySQL is a tool for migrating MySQL databases to MicrosoftSQL Server 2012, MicrosoftSQL Server 2014, MicrosoftSQL Server 2016, MicrosoftSQL Server 2017 on Windows and Linux, MicrosoftSQL Server 2019 on Windows and Linux, or Azure Microsoft Database. SSMA for MySQL converts MySQL database objects to SQL Server database objects, creates these objects in SQL Server, and then migrates data from MySQL to SQL Server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/mysql/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-mysql-mysqltosql?view=sql-server-ver15